# PhraseQuery with Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene

The only ways I can see to create a `PhraseQuery` are:

- `QueryParser.parse`, adding `"` to the start and end of the string (being careful to escape any special characters).
- `PhraseQuery.add` which needs the `Term`s to have been pre-analyzed.

Is there a way to construct a `PhraseQuery` by just applying the `Analyzer` to a `String` that is to be understood literally, and hasn't been manipulated as a query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible *(plus some junk to allow this to be posted).*